# Must Toolbar be wrapped with AppBarLayout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

The Code A is from the project [architecture samples](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples), the toolbar is wrapped with AppBarLayout.

I remove AppBarLayout and get Code B, and Code B works well just like Code A.

Must Toolbar be wrapped with AppBarLayout in Android Studio?

**Code A  (tasks_act.xml)**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tasks.TasksActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_actions" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Code B (tasks_act.xml)**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tasks.TasksActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
           app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
     

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_actions" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have scrolling effects in Toolbar. So AppBarLayout is used, see below images, you can achieve by using only AppBarLayout.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

`Toolbar` is just an usual `View` and it may be placed anywhere you want, even few in one XML. `AppBarLayout` is used to wrap `Toolbar` (or other `View`, e.g. `TabLayout`) and add some scroll-behavior change possibilities, when placed above some scrolling container like `ScrollView` or `RecyclerView` (you probably want to use `Nested` versions then)

check out nested classes listed in summary in on top of [`AppBarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout) doc - all related to scrolling (e.g. `OnOffsetChangedListener` or `ScrollingViewBehavior`)